# How to interpret the results of Fama-MacBeth regressions?

Tags: factor-models, asset-pricing, fama-french

I recently conducted a project for university, where I calculated the risk factors of the Fama-French 3Factor Model. For "SMB", the "size-premium", I get a negative result. What exactly does that tell me? How do I interpret this?